# Changing time on hosted site

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, momentjs, clock

I'm trying to convert date/time into local time, instead of UTC.

I'm getting the date and time from an API and this is giving it on UTC. So I need to convert it from UTC to local time, because after 6:00 pm it displays the date for the next day.

I've tried moment and 'toString', and it works on localhost but if I host it it still gives me UTC

```
let dateTesting = subscription.current_period_started_at._
let dateTesting2 = moment.utc(dateTesting).local().format('MM-DD-    YYYY HH:mm:ss')
let dateTesting3 = dateTesting.toString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")

console.log('- now in UTC', dateTesting)
console.log('dateTesting2 -------', dateTesting2)
console.log('without moment', dateTesting3)
```

The result from the code above is:

```
now in UTC 2019-01-09T17:16:25Z
dateTesting2 ------- 01-09-2019 17:16:25
without moment 2019-01-09T17:16:25Z
```

I want the date to appear the same as in my computer (-6 hours)

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "Local time" and "my computer": does it means that each client in different timezones (e.g: Hong Kong, London, New York) will get their "local time"?

Answer (score 0):

You could force the issue with something like

```
`moment.utc(dateTesting).local().format('MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss').subtract(6, 'hours)`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know your `TIME_ZONE` (sure), you can use:

```
const TIME_ZONE = -6;
const now = new Date(dateTesting);
now.setHours(now.getHours + TIME_ZONE) // or now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes()+ 60 * TIME_ZONE))
// because sometime TIME_ZONE is not `int`, example 4.5, 5.5, v.v,
//use with variable now, it's time same your time
```

If you run anywhere, you can get UTC time and convert it to your time, or you can use `getTimezoneOffset`:

```
const TIME_OFFSET = 360; // TIME_OFFSET = TIME_ZONE * 60

const now = new Date(time_of_any_where);
const thatOffset = now.getTimezoneOffset();
now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes+ thatOffset - TIME_OFFSET)

// Do something with `now`
```